# Change textview background color in custom ListView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am having one custom `ListView`. In custom `ListView`, each rows having 3 `TextView`.That 3 `TextView` `background` color should change `on click List item` by `listitemClick listner`. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, you need to handle click event in your custom adapter you are using to populate your list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can.

You need to implement `onClickListener` event for your view in `getView()` method in your custom adapter or you can simply implement `onItemClickListener` for the listview.

For ex,

```
yourViewObject.setonClickListener{.........

   textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
   textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
.... }
```

Comment: I am dynamically adding textview.if i set Like that it will apply?

Answer (score 0):

In the `onItemClickListener` for the listview add `textView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000)` (Replace with appropriate color code) where `textView` is a reference to the TextView whose color you want to change